# Closed form of the finite sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N}[\binom{N+n}{2n}a+\binom{N+n}{2n+1}b]x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I've been trying to find the closed form of the following sum.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}[\binom{N+n}{2n}a+\binom{N+n}{2n+1}b]x^n$$

Where *a* and *b* are arbitrary positive constants. I know that for a=b, Pascal's rule can be applied, but that is only one specific case I want to solve. This sum can of course be split into two.

$$a\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N+n}{2n}x^n+b\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N+n}{2n+1}x^n$$

These two sums are very close to the form $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n}x^n=(1+x)^N$, so I tried getting them into this form but was only left with a more complicated mess than I started with.

$$a\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{n!(N+n)!}{N!(2n)!}\binom{N}{n}x^n+b\sum_{n=0}^{N}(N-n)\frac{n!(N+n)!}{N!(2n+1)!}\binom{N}{n}x^n$$

I'm unsure how to progress further. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misspoke. What I mean is that I want to find the closed form, just as the closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N}{n}x^n$ is $(1+x)^N$. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N+n}{2n}x^n$, then checking several values of $x$ and $N$, we might find
$$
f_N(x)=(x+2)f_{N-1}(x)-f_{N-2}(x)
$$
with $f_{0}(x)=1$ and $f_1(x)=x+1$. The above can be proven for example by induction. Hence by theory of linear recurrences we have
$$
f_N(x)=A\cdot\alpha^N+B\cdot\beta^N
$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of the characteristic equation $t^2-(x+2)t+1=0$, i.e.
$$
\alpha,\beta=\frac{1}{2}(x+2\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x}).
$$
From $N=0$ and $N=1$ we can also find
$$
A,B=\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2(x+4)}.
$$

For $x^2+4x<0$ this would involve complex numbers. Notice also that expanding $\alpha^N$ and $\beta^N$ using binomial expansion, you would eventually get a sum representation without square roots (we are basically trading finite sum for a square root function).

One needs to be careful if $x=-4$ or $x=0$, then the characteristic equation has in fact one double root, so the expected form needs to be $f_N(x)=A\cdot \alpha^N+B\cdot N\cdot \alpha^N$ (however in these cases $\alpha=-1$ or $\alpha=1$ so the above simplifies a lot).

You can do the similar for $g_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N+n}{2n+1}x^n$, notice that in such case also
$$
g_N(x)=(x+2)g_{N-1}(x)-g_{N-2}(x)
$$
with $g_{0}(x)=0$ and $g_1(x)=1$. In fact, the whole $af_N(x)+bg_N(x)$ satisfies the same recurrence relation.

As noted, if $x \in (-4,0)$, then $\alpha,\beta$ are complex numbers with non-zero imaginary part, so the intermediate computations in the closed-form involve complex numbers. We can avoid that by either the finite sum (which kind of defeats the purpose of finding closed-form without the sum...), or alternatively we can express $\alpha$ in exponential form and use Euler's formula $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ and the imaginary parts cancel out (again there is a trade-off by introducing goniometric functions). See the summary below for such formula.

---

Let $h_N(x)=a\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N+n}{2n}x^n+b\sum_{n=0}^{N}\binom{N+n}{2n+1}x^n$, then we can summarize the above:

For $x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-4,0\}$:
$$
h_N(x)=
\frac{a\beta-ax-a-b}{\beta-\alpha}\alpha^N-\frac{a\alpha -ax-a-b}{\beta-\alpha}\beta^N\\
\alpha=\frac{1}{2}(x+2+\sqrt{x^2+4x}),\beta=\alpha^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(x+2-\sqrt{x^2+4x}).
$$
The above expression involves complex numbers as an intermediate step for $x \in (-4,0)$, even though the result is real.

For $x=0$:
$$
h_N(x)=
a+bN
$$

For $x=-4$:
$$
h_N(x)=
(-1)^N(a+(2a-b)N)
$$

For $x\in (-4,0)$:

$$
h_N(x)=\frac{ax+2b}{\sqrt{-x^2-4x}}\sin(Nt)+a\cos(Nt)\\
t=2\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{-x^2 - 4x}}{x+4}\right)
$$

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the matrix form of the recurrence:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}h_{N+1}(x)\\h_N(x)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x+2 & -1\\1& 0\end{pmatrix}^N\begin{pmatrix}ax+a+b\\a\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The above form together with fast exponentiation (e.g. [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)) can be efficient for computations with large $N$.

Comment: Just to clarify concerning your notation because I am unfamiliar with it, would $f_{N-1}(x)$ be $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom{N-1+n}{2n}x^n$ and so on?

Comment: @Tasea That is correct, we could use $f(N,x)$ instead of $f_N(x)$, I just used indeces since I wanted to emphasize that the recurrence is just in $N$

Comment: Thank you for expanding on your answer, but I'm still confused. Looking at this sum graphically on Desmos, it very clearly is real for $-4 < x < 0$, yet your result is not because, as you said, $\sqrt{x^2+4x}$ is complex for $x^2+4x<0$. Would it be possible to find a closed form of the sum on this interval?

Comment: @Tasea The result is real even if the intermediate computations are complex. You can either see the complex numbers cancel when expanding using binomial formula (but then you have again finite sum), or we can using exponential form of the complex number and cancel the imaginary parts explicitly, the prize is use of goniometric functions though, see my updated answer